# Want to convert ubuntu 12.04 desktop to server

Tags: 12.04

I am totally new to ubuntu and I want my ubuntu desktop to be converted to a server.
I searched the internet and got this:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo tasksel install server
apt-get install linux-server linux-image-server
apt-get –purge remove lightdm
```

Providing all that went well, you can edit your /etc/default/grub configuration file to update the following settings:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
( Comment out ‘GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT’ )
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console ( only for PC )
sudo update-grub
```

When the grub update has finished, you can reboot into Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server!

But after removing the desktop i am not able to install the server.

Any suggestions?
Are these queries correct?

Comment: how you cant install server ?

Comment: describe what happens in the system? can you elaborate why you cant install server? Do you have a desktop / login prompt where you can get a shell access to the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I believe you can install the server version as normal via cd. The setup manager will ask you if you want to keep your profile and update your desktop installation. Just a thought. --Regards.

Comment: Ya, I got an iso of ubuntu 12.04.3-server-amd64. Will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you're mentionning works only if you're in a text console (ctrl+alt+F1) or via ssh. If you try it in a graphical terminal, in your desktop, it's likely to fail.